# TurnJS ZoomIn and ZoomOut

Tags: turnjs

I am in a search of help. I am using TurnJS API and looking for ZoomIn and ZoomOut functionality using the buttons instead of click/tap on the flipbook. The Zoom-in and Zoom-out need to be factor based for e.g 20%. Each time I click ZoomIn, it should Zoom 20% upto 100 and Zoomout viceversa.

I tried to edit the zoom.js but was unsuccessful. Hope anybody can get back to me on this.